# Memoization decorator runs slower than original function

Tags: python, decorator

I'm doing memoized decorator exercise with fibonacci function. The memoized function should be much faster when the input gets large, because it returns the result from a dictionary instead of computing the result again.

I'm using `timeit.timeit()` to measure the execution time of the function with memoized on vs off.
The result I get are exactly the opposite of what I expect. The execution without the decorator runs much faster.

```
# memorized decorator for fibonacci series
def mem_fib(f):
    def wrapper(n):
        wrapper.d = {}  # create the attr member of THIS wrapper
        if n in wrapper.d:
            return wrapper.d[n]
        wrapper.d[n] = f(n)  # save f() return in a dict
        return wrapper.d[n]
    return wrapper

@mem_fib
def fibonacci(n):
    assert n >= 0
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
```

I'm running commands on PyCharm python's console.

***@with decorator***

```
>>> print(timeit.timeit('decorators.fibonacci(7)', setup='import decorators'))
19.6940833939
>>> print(timeit.timeit('decorators.fibonacci(10)', setup='import decorators'))
85.7157191166
```

***without the decorator***

```
>>> print(timeit.timeit('decorators.fibonacci(7)', setup='import decorators'))
5.10131571594
>>> print(timeit.timeit('decorators.fibonacci(10)', setup='import decorators'))
21.9784012801
```

I ran the timeit multiple times, I just put one output to sum it up. What am I missing?

Thanks

**Update**: Thanks to Daniel's answer, I found my mistake. I moved the dictionary creation outside of wrapper, and the results were much better.

```
>>> print(timeit.timeit('decorators.fibonacci(10)', setup='import decorators'))
0.248986574759
```

Comment: Have you tired it for way bigger values? My guess would be that for 7 and 10 that little overhead introduced by memoization is bigger than cost of actual calculations. I suppose that for fibbonacci(100) it may yield expected results.

Comment: Would that be because of your assert statement? And as a side note, you do not need the pass statement at the end. You can check for negative n, and raise an error, then check for base case and return. If both checks fail, it must be the recursive case, therefore no need to use else.

Comment: Mai this little change makes the code easier to read, thanks for the note

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create a new dictionary every time the function is called, because your `wrapper` function always does `wrapper.d = {}`. Therefore the cache will never be populated, and your code has the additional overhead of creating the dictionary each time.

That line should go outside that function, before you return it from `mem_fib`.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that, thanks! when I moved the dictionary creation outside of the wrapper (inside mem_fib) the results were as I expected

Comment: `print(timeit.timeit('decorators.fibonacci(10)', setup='import decorators'))
0.248986574759`